# Computing exponential object $A^{A}$ in category of irreflexive graphs

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, exponentiation

On p.333 of Conceptual Mathematics 2nd ed. we are asked to compute the exponential object $A^{A}$ in the category of irreflexive graphs, where $A$ is the graph of a single arrow `s -> t`.

(For context there is a graph $D$ that is the graph of a single dot `*`.

The book suggests using the properties of exponentials and graphs. For example to find the number of dots in $A^{A}$, find the number of maps $D \rightarrow A^{A}$, which is equivalent to the number of maps $A \times D \rightarrow A$. This is the same as the number of maps from the dots of $A$ to $A$, of which there are 4.

Similarly we can find the number of arrows by counting the maps of $A \rightarrow A^{A}$ which is the same as counting the maps of $A \times A \rightarrow A$ which there are 4, which are..

`(s, s)` and `(t, t`) must be mapped to `s` and `t` respectively, but `(s, t)` and `(t, s)` can be mapped to either `s` or `t`, hence 4.

**So I know there are 4 dots and 4 arrows.. but I don't know how to map the arrows onto the dots.**

Context: In the category of graphs an object is two sets $X$ (the edges of the graph) and $P$ (the nodes of the graph) equipped with two arrows $s, t: X \rightarrow P$ which correspond to the source and target of the edge. An arrow between two graphs is two arrows $f: X \rightarrow X'$ and $g: P \rightarrow P'$ which preserves source and target:

$$ g \circ s = s' \circ f $$
$$ g \circ t = t' \circ f $$

Comment: This is more or less obvious (mentioning this since it can help to be told that things are easy). Hint: draw the morphisms, then interpret what you have drawn itself as a graph. This is more or less what the cartesian-closedness of the the category of quivers (a recommendable synonym for the graphs you are considering) is about: interpreting an illustration of a morphism itself as an object (i.e. quiver).

Comment: Another thing: it might be good to reconsider your formulation "arrows onto the dots".

Comment: More precise would have been for me to say: "interpreting an illustration of _all_ the morphisms itself as an object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see how the source and target mappings work, what you really want to do is, for a given edge $f:A\to A^A$, take the transpose of the composite $ev\circ id_A\times (f\circ\mathsf{src})$, where $\mathsf{src}$ is the inclusion of $D$ into the source of $A$'s edge. The composite is patently a morphism $A\times D\to A$, and its transpose is therefore a vertex $s_f:D\to A^A$. The resulting function $f\mapsto s_f$ works out to be the source function for the exponential graph.

If instead you use $\mathsf{tgt}:D\to A$ (let's call it), the inclusion of $D$ into the target vertex of $A$, then you have an analogous $f\mapsto t_f:D\to A^A$ forming a target function for the exponential graph.

More concretely, given a graph morphism $f:A\times A\to A$, let $f_V$ be the vertex part of the morphism. All the abstract nonsense above says is that the source function is $f\mapsto f_V(-,s)$ and the target function is $f\mapsto f_V(-,t)$.

Comment: Hm I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the last step. I can see how one arrives at $s_f$ and $t_f$ but from there how does that help me identify the corresponding source and target?

Comment: Nevermind figured it out! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm having trouble figuring out the evaluation map now.. any tips? I have $A \times A^{A}$ which seems to have 4 bare dots which seems weird..

Comment: Evaluation is simpler than it sounds. The action on edges can only be constant, since there's only one edge in the codomain. And the action on vertices is just regular set evaluation, which you should be able to see by playing with the diagrams for a bit.

Comment: Ah yep I played around with using $A \times D$ to see what needed to happen to make the diagram commute and I think I got it - thanks again!